# does process.env.NODE_ENV sets to 'production' automatically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, environment-variables

I was reading someone's code and came across this line.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { ...
```

This is a node.js application with express server and reactjs front end. So lets say we deploy it to heroku will it get this NODE_ENV variable automatically(or set by heroku itself) or do I have to set it manually as we set other env variables in development server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated here, NODE_ENV is set to production per default if you deploy it on Heroku:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#runtime-behavior

Answer (score 0):

process.env refers to the environment variables on the system. This depends a whole lot on where the application runs and how the system is configured. Herocku does not know if a specific version of your app is in test or production. So the developer has defined an environment and added 'production' as a variable in that environment.

If you use npm you can add variables with script command

```
{
  ..
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "corss-env ENVIRONMENT=development ..",
    "prod": "cross-env ENVIRONMENT=production .."
  }
  ..
}
```

and use the appropriate command as run according to setting.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env

Answer (score 0):

Inside in your project in Heroku, you can set all environments variables.
Go in your project > settings > Config Vars and set NODE_ENV production.